# PHP Regex for validation certain number format

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression which validates any one of the below formats:

- +10%
- -123
- +5.5
- +50
- 99
- 99.99
- -20%
- 25% (this should not be validated)

(`%` without any `+` or `-` should not be validated)

I tried to use `preg_match('/^[+-]?(\d+\.)?(\d+)[%]?$/', $value)` but this also validates `25%`.
Can anyone share regex which validates the above format?

Comment: Are you saying that positive percentages are not valid, but negative ones are?  Also, can the number have a decimal component?

Comment: % without any +/- is not valid

Comment: Another [idea with lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/Dko8tG/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this using [conditional sub-pattern in PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php) that avoids repeating whole number matching pattern again in alternation:

```
^([+-])?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?(1)%)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rTCOL/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `([+-])?`: Match `+` or `-` in optional group #1
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?`: Match dot followed by 1+ digits in an optional non-capturing group
- `(?(1)%)?`: Conditional subpattern. If group #1 is present then match `%` as optional match.
- `$`: End

Comment: This does validate `99.99` as you can see on https://regex101.com/r/7rTCOL/2

Comment: Nice solution with the conditional ++

Answer (score 2):

I might just keep it simple here and use an alternation:

```
^(?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[+-]\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)$
```

### Demo

The tricky part of your requirement is that the leading sign is optional for a non percentage number, but mandatory for a percentage.  The alternation makes it easy to separate out these two concerns.

Comment: Note that the numbers can be floating like 99.99, +9.5% etc. I have updated by Question

Comment: `?:` What does this mean?

Comment: @MegaPsycho `?:` just turns off capturing for the group containing the optional decimal.  In this case, we are using parentheses only to form a closure around part of the pattern, but we don't really want to capture just the decimal component.  It is optional, but best practice to use it.